# Jquery: div Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, button, anchor

knewb here,
I have made a textless, blocked, div clickable with Jquery and CSS. 
Upon click I would like to load a new URL into the browser thus taking my visitor away from my website to say stackoverflow.com. 
Can you do that with Jquery? If so how?

```
 #star{
    width:130px;
    height:40px;
    outline:1px solid orange;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

<div id="star">star</div>

<script>    
    $("#star").click(function(evt){
        $(this).html("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    });
</script>
```

Second question
I have to have the div transparent or empty so the menu background shows, (no slicing.).
Can I or and should I do this with a transparent gif?

BTW: also how do I modify the code for a local URL?
Thank you!

Comment: may I ask why you don't just use an `<a>` with the same CSS? If you did, you could just give it an `href` and avoid the use of jQuery altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The first part is relatively easy:

```
$("#star").click(function(evt){
    window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
});
```

As for transparency, simply add the following to your CSS:

```
#star {
    /* other stuff */
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Or, if you don't necessarily need full cross-browser compatibility:

```
#star {
    /* other stuff */
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

The above will make the element's `background-color` white, with an alpha transparency of `0.1` (`0` being fully transparent, `1` being fully opaque).

Note, I wasn't quite sure what you meant by 'local url,' but if you mean is it possible to use a relative path, for example to change:

```
'http://server.com/news/index.html'
```

To:

```
'http://server.com/some/other/directory/index.html'
```

without using an absolute path in the JavaScript, then the following should work:

```
$("#star").click(function(evt){
    window.location.pathname = '/somewhere_else/on/the/same/server';
});
```